# C++ GUI drawing lines with math

Tags: c++, math, win32gui

I'm trying to draw straight lines with squares between 2 points, given with `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` (they give me values for `startIndex` and `endIndex`). When I do the math with pen and paper I always get the right results but there is some kind of a bug in my code which I just don't get. Basically there is a grid of squares, each given a value from 0 on.

[image: grid]

This is my code so far:

```
int xDiff = endX - startX;
int yDiff = endY - startY;
int steps = xDiff > yDiff ? xDiff : yDiff;
for (int i = steps; i >= 1; i--){
  startIndex += (endIndex - startIndex) / i;
  startIndex = round(startIndex);
}
```

Lines going straight up or down and sideways and at 45 degree angle get drawn right, others shatter to pieces. Any help would be appreciated madly.

```
//----------------------
```

Edit: Dammit, I think my formula is faulty in same cases. I'll have to change my approach.

```
//------------------------
```

Last edit: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, Bresenheim did it :)

Found this amazing tutorial: [Bresenheim](http://members.chello.at/~easyfilter/bresenham.html)

Comment: What is the type of `startIndex` and `endIndex`? By the way, what you want may be [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: What is the purpose of `startIndex` and `endIndex`? How are you checking the result?

Comment: startX and endX sound like they are actual x-coordinates. Which means that xDiff and yDiff might be both negative in one computation. How about steps = ceil(euclidean_norm(xDiff,yDiff)), if time is not an issue?

Comment: `startIndex` and `endIndex` are both `int`. Mouse gets point coordinates from up and down and they are converted into an index in the grid (0 - 99). Then I use them to calculate the indexes in between to form a straight line. The result is drawn on the screen so it's obvious when things go wrong. Kind of messy, I know. I'm thinking about counting the values in between in point values and then changing them to index but this should also work.

Comment: And I change `startIndex` into a float before the `for()` and if `xDiff` and `yDiff` are negative they are multiplied with -1

Comment: Look up "bresenham's algorithm".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm